# User defined packages in Java

Tags: java, classpath, package, cannot-find-symbol

I have been editing, running, and compiling code in Notepad++ using NppExec. I have set a classpath at C:\Java. This folder contains: C:\Java\com\DOMAINNAMEWITHHELD\Classes. Inside this folder I have 3 .java files, and one .class file (Runner.java, Pirate.java, Ninja.java, and Pirate.class). I was running these files in a folder on a flash drive, and none of the three could see each other. So I moved them to my new classpath defined directory, and still cannot get anything except:

C:\Java\com\DOMAINNAMEWITHHELD\Classes\Runner.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        phil.throwAStar(tim);

throwAStar() is defined in Ninja, and called in Runner.

In the three source files, I defined a package like this:

package com.DOMAINNAMEWITHHELD.Classes;

If I am in any other directory, and try:

import com.DOMAINNAMEWITHHELD.Classes.*;

I get the exact same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get the error when you compile and run from `C:\Java\com\DOMAINNAMEWITHHELD\Classes`? I mean move to the directory, compile and run.

Comment: I can compile Pirate just fine, but it does not reference Runner or Ninja. Ninja references Pirate, and Runner references both. And yes, phil is a ninja. He is created in Runner like this: Ninja phil= new Ninja(); and this calls a public string setName(): public String setName(){
  System.out.println("What would you like your ninja to be named?");
  String n= scanner.nextLine();
  return n;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Once I cleaned up some syntax errors from troubleshooting, and trying to keep up with class, I finally got Runner, Ninja, Pirate, and now Wizard to compile, and run. In case you guys are wondering how to run a .class file contained in a package:

Let's say the file is: C:\Java\com\DOMAINWITHHELD\classes\Runner.class

Type this into a command prompt to run Runner:

cd C:\Java

java com.DOMAINWITHHELD.classes.Runner

Now the class 'Runner' in the package 'com.DOMAINWITHHELD.classes' should execute.